# Trying to remove element from DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a DOM element that can be accessed with JavaScript using

```
rectangle=document.getElementsByTagName("rectangle")[index];
```

I am trying to remove it from the DOM, using jQuery, as follows.

```
element=jQuery('rectangle').get(index);
element.remove();
```

However Firebug returns the error

```
TypeError: element.remove is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.get` returns a standard DOMElement. Create a jQuery object from it and *then* `$.remove` will work.

```
element=jQuery(jQuery('rectangle').get(index));
element.remove();
```

Better yet, do this in one step and use `$.eq` instead of `$.get`:

```
element=jQuery('rectangle').eq(index);
element.remove();
```

Comment: Or just `element=jQuery('rectangle').eq(index)` (without having to wrap it with `jQuery()` :)

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helps you, please don't forget to accept it via clicking the check to the left.